# Spring boot 3.2.2 upgrade related Warnings - Batch application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, java-21

I am upgrading Java from 8 to 21 and Spring boot from 2.2 to 3.2.2  for a large batch applications following the migration guides for spring boot and batch and Java migration guides  .. After having fixed several of the challenges , the batch now runs fine .. however I see these WARNing when I start up the application .. Any inputs on how I can fix these ?

```
Line  17: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.132+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'datasourceConfiguration' of type [com.abc.batch.pcf.configuration.DatasourceConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  18: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.173+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'abcHikariConfig' of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  21: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.428+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'abcDataSource' of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  22: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.442+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.jpa-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  23: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.445+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.jpa.hibernate-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  24: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.451+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  25: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.452+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration$$Lambda/0x000001a0423cc9c8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  26: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.454+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  27: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.459+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  28: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.464+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionExecutionListeners' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.ExecutionListenersTransactionManagerCustomizer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  29: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.469+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.transaction-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  30: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.470+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  31: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.485+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.DataSourceInitializationConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.DataSourceInitializationConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  32: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.488+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.sql.init-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  33: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.494+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  34: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.496+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  35: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.502+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.batch-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  36: 2024-01-27T12:18:29.996+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'batchDataSourceInitializer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  37: 2024-01-27T12:18:30.010+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  38: 2024-01-27T12:18:30.013+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' of type [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  39: 2024-01-27T12:18:30.030+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'persistenceManagedTypes' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SimplePersistenceManagedTypes] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  45: 2024-01-27T12:18:30.894+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener' of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  48: 2024-01-27T12:18:32.228+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  49: 2024-01-27T12:18:32.229+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy122] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  50: 2024-01-27T12:18:32.233+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionManager' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
    Line  51: 2024-01-27T12:18:32.239+02:00  WARN 1736 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not contain sufficient information to be sure but the warnings are most likely produced by the unconditonal exposure of the `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor` that has been introduced with Spring Batch 5.1.

If that's the case, you should be able to get rid of the warnings by adding the following code snippet to one of your configuration classes:

```
@Bean
public static BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessorRemover() {
  return registry -> registry.removeBeanDefinition("jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor");
}
```

More information on this issue can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4519

It could potentially be also other beans that are triggering these warnings. The problem might have also been there since before the upgrade as the log level of this logging has only recently been elevated from `INFO` to `WARN`.